# Is it common practice for foreign warships to dock in Australian ports without being announced to the public?

Tags: australia

This [article](https://mobile.abc.net.au/news/2019-06-03/chinese-warships-enter-sydney-harbour-south-china-sea-claims/11172578) describes how some Chinese military vessels docked in Australia without being pre-announced to the public.

It's getting attention because these are Chinese warships and it's close to the timing of the Tiananmen Square massacre. if it were another country would it go unnoticed

I'm really after an understanding of the general political conventions and examples in prior history, so I can understand if the way it is generally being reported is reasonable or unreasonable.

It does not have to have media attention to be what I would consider publically announced. It could be in a registry somewhere that is accessible to interested parties.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be publicly announced? I am sure foreign ships pull into ports around the world all the time with little word as they try to avoid drawing attention to that for security reasons.

Comment: @JoeW Foreign military ships require explicit government permission to enter another country's waters. Citizens generally have a right to freely know their country's international relations. In many countries, unless you can show the information is classified, it is public.

Comment: It seems those who needed to know knew well in advance. https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2019/jun/03/three-chinese-warships-arrive-in-sydney-harbour-for-four-day-stopover

Comment: By not being announced to the public do you mean there was no public record of it anywhere until after the fact, or that there was a publicly available record of the impending arrival but you'd have to put in effort to find it?  There's often a difference between "the public has a right to access this information" and "the public has a right to access this information easily".  The law in general is publicly available in most jurisdictions, but good luck easily finding what you need in a lot of them!

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I updated the question to highlight if it's only on an obscure listing that only interested people can find then its public enough

Answer (score 3):

I often see foreign naval vessels coming in to dock in Brisbane

In the last few months I have seen 2 different Singaporean naval vessels docked at Hamilton.  I have never seen a press release or official announcement of their arrival.